# Change Array Keys and sort them via PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key, key-value

I looked at different options how to sort arrays. But somehow none of the given PHP commands suit my purpose.

Example - I have an array like this :

```
Array
(
    [abc] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [5] => 5
        )

)
```

But I want to change the array to

```
[0] => 2
[1] => 3
[2] => 5
```

In other words I want to remove all keys - sort all values from LOW to HIGH and then just give em the keys from zero to X
It's much easier to work with such an array if you want to use some loops like (for, while, etc.)

Comment: Does your original array have multiple string keys that you want to merge together?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `sort` and `array_values`.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'abc'   => array(
        2 => 2,
        5 => 5,
        3 => 3,
    ),
);

sort($array['abc']);

$array = array_values($array['abc']);

print_r($array);
```

I've popped up an example at http://3v4l.org/51naW